# Illegal attempt to establish a relationship

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am getting this nasty crash and error.

The crash occurs when this code runs:

```
    Address *address = [[Address alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];

        //Crashes here!
        [person addAddressObject:address];
```

`Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'person' between objects in different contexts`

The entire console error is below.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'person' between objects in different contexts (source = <Address: 0x1f87e270> (entity: Address; id: 0x1f87e2b0 <x-coredata:///Address/t748EE284-0311-4489-9654-1D902EB0D4CC2> ; data: {
    addressLine1 = "";
    addressLine2 = "";
    addressLine3 = "";
    city = "";
    country = "";
    person = nil;
    state = "";
    title = "";
    zip = "";
}) , destination = <Person: 0x1ed9e1e0> (entity: Person; id: 0x1ed9c710 <x-coredata://ED0283A9-A847-407E-BFEC-CF2BF85C6A9C/Person/p1> ; data: {
    address =     (
        "0x1f87e2b0 <x-coredata:///Address/t748EE284-0311-4489-9654-1D902EB0D4CC2>",
        "0x1ed93e70 <x-coredata://ED0283A9-A847-407E-BFEC-CF2BF85C6A9C/Address/p1>"
    );
    favourite = nil;
    firstName = Josh;
    lastName = Kahane;
}))'
```

I have no clue how to fix this. Presumably it thinks there is two different managedObjectContexts? However, in my app I only ever reference that made in my app delegate like so (run at viewDidLoad):

```
if (managedObjectContext == nil)
    {
        managedObjectContext = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        NSLog(@"After managedObjectContext: %@",  managedObjectContext);
    }
```

Any ideas as to where to start looking for the discrepancies? Thanks.

EDIT:

New discovery. Just before the app crashes, I've NSLogged both the address and person managed object contexts. Turns out the address context is `(null)`, even if I run the check right before hand to set the context if its nil.

Comment: First suggestions: 1) Log `[address managedObjectContext]` and `[person managedObjectContext]` to make sure that the context is the same. 2) Could it be that the view is unloaded at some time, and the next check `if (managedObjectContext == nil) ...` creates a new MOC? 3) Set a breakpoint where the MOC is created (in the AppDelegate) to see if it is called twice.

Comment: Little extra discovery, I've added it to my question. Any idea why its null even if I check the context before hand?

Comment: Why do you use `... insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil]` in the creation of `address`? Shouldn't that be `... insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext]` ?

Comment: I don't insert it into a context initially incase the user cancels their action. This way it can be kept as a temporary object and then I insert the object when the user reaches a point of confirmation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're inserting it into a nil `managedObjectContext`.

You'll need to insert the object into the `NSManagedObjectContext` that you use for the entity.  i.e. `managedObjectContext`.

In the alloc init of the Address object.

Reading your comment in the OP.

You should either...

Save all the required values and then at the point on confirmation create the Address object and insert it all in one go.

Or...

Create the object and insert it creating all the relationships and then if the user presses cancel just delete the object.

I'd do one of these two to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

```
Address *address = [[Address alloc] initWithEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext] insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

Why are you inserting it into a nil context. Shouldn't you be passing the managed object context instead of nil.

Comment: I don't insert it into a context initially incase the user cancels their action. This way it can be kept as a temporary object and then I insert the object when the user reaches a point of confirmation.